# Team Balancing / Score Normalisation for gamification

Tags: recreational-mathematics, algorithmic-game-theory

This is the first time I post in Mathematics as I'm normally in programing. But for this question, I think I can get better help here.

I'm trying to create a gamification system where different teams are competing against each other to score points by doing certain tasks.

The problem I have is that the teams aren't equal balanced. They have a different amount of players and workload. So I need to figure out a formula to balance the score or create a "handicap" to let the smaller teams have same chance.

| Team | Players | Total Cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 500 |
| B | 4 | 4000 |
| C | 6 | 5000 |
| D | 4 | 3000 |
| E | 6 | 7000 |

Cases is what they score points on so it changed every day.
Easiest calculation would be 1 case = 1 point

But for Team A who is a small team of only 2 people and a very low amount of cases every month. The people in that team have no chance competing against the people in team E as they have way more cases per person.

What I would like to end up with is this.

| Player | Cases | multiplier | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Player 1 | nn | xx | bb points |
| Player 2 | nn | xx | bb points |
| Player 3 | nn | xx | bb points |
| Player 4 | nn | xx | bb points |

...and so on.

Players compete against each other disregarding which team they are in and thanks to the multiplier their score will be fairly equal.

**Question is**; How do I calculate the multiplier for each team?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Solving for $x_i$ in $c_i\cdot x_i = b$ for $i$th player with $c_i$ cases, and $b$ is equal for all players? So, $x_i = b/c_i$? Or... ?

Comment: Solving the xx(multiplier). So I can use cases time the multiplier to get an score for that player.